# Is there a way to parallelize find without piping to xargs / parallel?

Tags: parallel-processing, grep, find

I am trying to parallelize the following command:

```
find . -type f -name "{file_regex}" -exec zgrep -cH "{match_regex}" {} \;
```

I'm hoping to run this across 100 cores. I currently run the `find` separately in python and capture the stdout, and then create a threadpool and run `zgrep -cH ${match_regex} {file_path}` to get the matches. Is there a simpler way of doing this aside from just piping to xargs/parallel?

Comment: I wouldn't be too concerned about how many cores are available, I'd be more concerned about how many i/o heads the disk (array) has.

Comment: it's a beegfs cluster, it should be able to handle very parallel reads like this

Comment: Yes, it probably should, unless there is some weird decomposition of work.

Comment: I'd recommend using [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) instead, it is recursive and works in parallel by default (IIRC you can finetune a few settings as well regarding parallelism). You'll have to use `-z` option for searching compressed files, `-g` option to specify file glob, etc. Check out https://github.com/phiresky/ripgrep-all as well.

Comment: ripgrep would work, but i'm planning on running this on a cluster node, which might not have the binary installed, so I'm hoping to use just the standard linux utilities if possible